# I need empty fields in multitable query

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

This should be easy for you, but I'm lost here:

I have a database with 4 tables: orders, clients, products, orders_products

I need to fetch all clients, with all of their orders, *including* the ones that don't have any order.

I'm only getting the ones that have made an order. Poor old "Nick" in the Clients table won't show up.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
SELECT c.name clientname, o.id orderID, GROUP_CONCAT(p.name) productNAMEs,
    GROUP_CONCAT(p.id) productIDs
FROM clients c, orders o, orders_products op, products p
WHERE c.id = o.client_id
AND c.status = 1
AND o.id = op.order_id
AND p.id = op.product_id
GROUP BY c.name
```

See table definitions here:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bTRSLfYTa19S2EpE2zKwUv/7

### Update

@scaisedge came up with an answer that includes clients without orders:

```
SELECT c.name clientname, o.id orderID, GROUP_CONCAT(p.name) productNAMEs, 
GROUP_CONCAT(p.id) productIDs
FROM clients c
LEFT JOIN  orders o ON c.id = o.client_id
LEFT  JOIN  orders_products op ON o.id = op.order_id
LEFT  JOIN  products p  ON p.id = op.product_id  
WHERE c.status = 1
GROUP BY c.name
```

You can see the results here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8bGcQJSbSFmKMUo1tLuZuA/1

It seems that not using JOINs was my problem.

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and _easier to convert to outer join_ if needed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use explicit join sintax and left join for retrive also row that don't match

```
SELECT c.name clientname, o.id orderID, GROUP_CONCAT(p.name) productNAMEs, 
GROUP_CONCAT(p.id) productIDs
FROM clients c
LEFT JOIN  orders o ON c.id = o.client_id
LEFT  JOIN  orders_products op ON o.id = op.order_id
LEFT  JOIN  products p  ON p.id = op.product_id  
WHERE c.status = 1
GROUP BY c.name
```

Comment: i'm a new user in SQL, so i will have to learn about JOINS :)

But your code doesen't return "Nick" client, so it's not the solution i need: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ujcc7eVvQtB7SPLt6FmBPR/0

Comment: @Giannis  . answer  updated .. retunr 3 rows also the 3rdwit null values   https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ujcc7eVvQtB7SPLt6FmBPR/0

Comment: Thanks, it works. Now i need to get my hands into JOINS so i can figure out what they do :)

Thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I recommand you to use JOIN's to UNIFY the tables data. A JOIN clause is used to combine rows from two or more tables, based on a related column between them.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

```
SELECT *
FROM clients LEFT JOIN orders ON clients.id = orders.client_id
     LEFT JOIN orders_products ON clients.id = orders_products.order_id 
     LEFT JOIN products ON products.id = orders_products.product_id
WHERE clients.status = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the link, i will check it out

Answer (score 0):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

Also, your `GROUP BY` needs to match the unaggregated columns in the `SELECT`.

I'm not sure if you intend this:

```
SELECT c.name as clientname, o.id as orderID,        
       GROUP_CONCAT(p.name) as productNAMEs,
       GROUP_CONCAT(p.id) productIDs
FROM clients c left join
     orders o
     on c.id = o.client_id left join
     orders_products op
     on o.id = op.order_id left join
     products p
     on p.id = op.product_id
WHERE c.status = 1
GROUP BY c.name, o.id;
```

Or:

```
SELECT c.name as clientname,      
       GROUP_CONCAT(p.name) as productNAMEs,
       GROUP_CONCAT(p.id) productIDs
FROM clients c left join
     orders o
     on c.id = o.client_id left join
     orders_products op
     on o.id = op.order_id left join
     products p
     on p.id = op.product_id
WHERE c.status = 1
GROUP BY c.name;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, i'm getting an error on the suggested code: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gZYKsLPpiKJ9hHveSs57Eq/1